# Filter unpublished nodes, even for Admin

Tags: views

How can I filter out unpublished nodes in a view even if the user viewing it is an administrator?

Comment: what version of drupal / views are you using?

Comment: D7 and latest views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you just want to switch the filter you are using from

```
Content: Published or admin
Filters out unpublished content if the current user cannot view it.
```

to

```
Content: Published
Whether or not the content is published.
```